# Filtrar por mes - Laravel + Carbon

Tags: laravel, eloquent, carbon

Quiero filtrar todas las operaciones de este mes de un vendedor X

```
$clave_vendedor_siac = Auth::user()->siac_codigo_vendedor;
    $vendedor = Vendedor::find($clave_vendedor_siac);

    $hoy= Carbon::now();

    $operaciones = Operacion::where('ope_tipo',5)
            ->where('ope_vende',2)
            ->where('ope_fecha','>=',$hoy->format('M-Y'))                
            ->get();

    dd($operaciones);
```

El formato en el que viene de la base de datos es el siguiente dd/mm/yyyy.
Como puedo filtrar por el campo ope fecha?
Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias formas de resolver esto, voy a escribir una que se me ocurre rápidamente, aprovechando a Carbon:

Puedes utilizar el método `startOfMonth()`, que devuelve el momento en el cual inició el mes de la instancia (con hora en 00:00:00), luego formateas dicha fecha para que pueda ser comparada con tus fechas, y haces la consulta.

```
$inicioMes = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();

$inicioFormateado = $inicioMes->format('d/m/Y'); // el formato que sea...

$operaciones = Operacion::where('ope_tipo',5)
        ->where('ope_vende',2)
        ->where('ope_fecha','>=',$inicioFormateado)                
        ->get();
```

Comment: Te añado 2 correcciones aquí mismo. La primera es que a eloquent no hace falta formatearle las fechas si son objetos Carbon, y la segunda existen los operadores whereMonth y WhereYear que laravel usa para evitar problemas, y hacerlos mas legibles, por lo que yo cambiaría `->where('ope_fecha','>=',$inicioFormateado) `  por `->whereMonth('ope_fecha', $inicioMes)->whereYear('ope_fecha', $inicioMes)`

Comment: Usar dos líneas en vez de una no parece ser una mejora, ¿cuáles problemas?. En cuanto al formato, es posible que tengas razón, muy rara vez he utilizado formatos distintos, pero al ser objetos Carbon es posible que no necesite cambiar el formato, tendría que probarlo, en todo caso esta respuesta la escribí desde el móvil, fue una simple idea rápida.

Comment: Es simplemente por "humanizar" y facilitar la lectura. Como dije esto es una sugerencia solo.

Comment: Bueno, no veo que diga la palabra "sugerencia" en tu comentario, sin embargo sí veo la palabra **corrección**.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas filtrar por el mes actual puedes hacerlo directamente desde mysql con la siguiente sentencia:

```
$clave_vendedor_siac = Auth::user()->siac_codigo_vendedor;
    $vendedor = Vendedor::find($clave_vendedor_siac);

    $hoy= Carbon::now();

    $operaciones = Operacion::where('ope_tipo',5)
            ->where('ope_vende',2)
            ->whereRaw('month(ope_fecha) = month(now())')
            ->whereRaw('year(ope_fecha) = year(now())')                 
            ->get();
```

explicacion:

- la funcion **whereRaw** te permite agregar un query especial sin necesidad de ser validado por el ORM
- **month** es una funcion nativa de mysql que obtiene el mes de una fecha dad.
- **now()** es una funcion de mysql que te da la fecha actual, es como usar Carbon::now() pero directamente en BD

entonces te funciona perfectamente sacando el mes de cada operacion y comparandolo con el mes actual de la BD.

Comment: Estoy trabajando con una BD en SqlServer

Comment: la funcion month y year son sentenxis standart de sql, por lo cual lo encontraras en cualquier motor de BD, solo debes reemplazar now() por GETDATE(). y deberia funcionarte